# Any Experience with LED grab rails?

Tags: toilet, led

My first post here. I came across these new type of grab rails at Bunnings (Australia) which come fitted with a sound-activated LED light.

This will be for my in-laws who are old and I think it makes a lot of sense to have these LEDs fitted into the bar. But never heard of this company before and cannot see any online reviews either.

They seem to be the only company offering this product in the market.

Here is the link to the LED grab rails - [LED Grab Rails](https://evekare.com.au/products/grab-rails/led-grab-rail-300mm/)

Answer (score 2):

#### Batteries Not Included

Actually, maybe batteries **are** included, I actually don't know. But I do know it is battery powered.

That is very, very **good** from a safety standpoint - electricity and water don't mix, so any mains-powered device in a bathroom has to be built properly, and installed properly, to be safe. Battery powered devices (or at least, devices like this powered by AA batteries) are pretty safe.

However, as crazy as it sounds, that may be really **bad** from a usefulness standpoint. Specifically, the batteries will wear out. I would guess they will last somewhere between a week and a couple of months. Once they wear out, they will need to be replaced, probably several times a year.

**Do you think your in-laws will change the batteries?** If they will, great. If they won't, then you have overpaid for a grab bar to get a temporary gimmick.

A more expensive (because you'll need professional installation - my understanding is that in Australia homeowners can't do much electrical work themselves) solution is a ceiling light with a motion sensor. These are quite common in public bathrooms, but there is no reason you couldn't have one in a residential bathroom. Then if one of your in-laws wanders into the bathroom in the middle of the night, they will get the full bathroom light instead of (essentially) a small flashlight.

Comment: What about one of those motion sensor light switches?

Comment: Yes, a motion sensor could be in the switch or attached to the fixture.

Comment: Excellent, that might be cheaper.

Comment: "Battery life expectancy is estimated to be 12 months, if the light is activated 20 times per day." - FAQ

Comment: I leave a small decorative light (LED fairy lights) on in the bathroom all night and it's plenty. a motion-activated ceiling light can be quite jarring at 3am, and looks silly coming on in the day when not needed.

Comment: 12 months is impressive. If it works that well then it sounds much more reasonable. As far as light during the day when not needed, I nearly always turn on the light when I go to the bathroom. I don't necessarily turn on the light in other rooms (e.g., my kitchen and dining room have plenty of natural light, depending on the time of day), but bathroom - even though it has natural light I nearly always turn on the light. To each his own.